# How to make the pandas row a column name?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

When I create the Pandas dataframe, it detects the empty line at the top of the excel file as the column name and shows it as unnamed. But my column names should be the concentration names on the bottom line of it. How can I do this in a pandas? (Editing in Excel is a solution, but I want to automatically edit multiple excel files with python)

[image]

Comment: Try passing `header=[0,1]` or just `header=[1]` to `pd.read_excel`.

Comment: Another option would be `skiprows=0`

Comment: As a new user please follow this guide. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Answer (score 0):

I think the column over there is not representing any column it is simply indication that  there are many number of columns there. If it is a column and u don't want it u can simply drop it

```
df.drop("...")
```

if still it is still not resolved do comment.